# macOS: You are opening the application “SubApp” for the first time. Are you sure you want to open this application?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

I'm building a macOS application where I created a sub-app(an app type subproject). The sub-app is configured with skip install = false and copied as a wrapper to Contents/MacOS of the Main app. I intend to open the sub-app from the main app, I used NSWorkspace NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication(withBundleIdentifier:). However, I'm getting the dialog message first time the sub-app is launched from the main app 
`You are opening the application “Sub-app” for the first time. Are you sure you want to open this application?`. How can I avoid this kind of message, I'm not so sure if this is fine for a user using the app for the first time. 
Is there a way I can suppress this message, or a better way to implement the solution.

I'm new to macOS application development.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if this helps or not, but here's an answer on Super User: https://superuser.com/a/828306/448370